OpenSSL Ed25519 with sodium php is not working
I a trying to encrypt a message with PHP 7.4 Sodium.
This function:
sodium_crypto_box_seal('Hello World', $pemPublicKey);

Returns error:
Argument 2 must be CRYPTO_BOX_PUBLICKEYBYTES long.

$pemPublicKey is stored in a file public33.pem and I retrieve it like this:
 $pemPublicKey = file_get_contents(PEM_FILES_PATH . '/public33.pem');  
 $pemPublicKey = str_replace('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '', $pemPublicKey);
 $pemPublicKey = str_replace('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', '', $pemPublicKey);
 $pemPublicKey = trim($pemPublicKey);
 $pemPublicKey = base64_decode($pemPublicKey);
 $enc = sodium_crypto_box_seal('Hello World', $pemPublicKey);

The contents of the public33.pem file are:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEA5d3iW1eV66LJbBub+hrZinr2Uky6RfqYG3VNxQnCl4U=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

I have checked and the contents of the file are read correctly.
The primary key and public key file was created like this:

openssl genpkey -algorithm Ed25519 -out private33.bin
openssl pkey -in private33.pem -pubout -out public33.pem 


PHP 7.4 reached its end of life more than a year ago. It should not be used anymore at all.

@GeraldSchneider yes I know that but for the moment I have to go with php7.4. Do you have any suggestion about my prob?

sodium_crypto_box_seal() does not require a public PEM key in X.509/SPKI format, but the raw 32 bytes public key. You can extract this from the public PEM key as the last 32 bytes of the Base64 decoded body.
A second issue is that you are using a key pair of the wrong type for sodium_crypto_box_seal() since X25519 is applied under the hood (s. here). You do not need an Ed25519 key pair, but an X25519 key pair, so you have to adapt the OpenSSL statement and generate new keys:
openssl genpkey -algorithm X25519 -out private33.pem
...

PHP code:
<?php
// Encryption
$pemSPKI = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VuAyEACK2b1mIhIdgont5UdtboDiHQYMJlrJKjCBaWk1LbFS8=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
$pemSPKI = str_replace('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '', $pemSPKI);
$pemSPKI = str_replace('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', '', $pemSPKI);
$pemSPKI = trim($pemSPKI);
$derSPKI = base64_decode($pemSPKI);
$rawPublic = substr($derSPKI, -32);
$ct = sodium_crypto_box_seal('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', $rawPublic);
print('ciphertext: ' .  bin2hex($ct) . PHP_EOL);

// Decryption
$pemPkcs8 = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VuBCIEIFAjP8X4es8alPOfr7ew/JKePnBvA49xiz2R0ZxO5wBZ
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'; 
$pemPkcs8 = str_replace('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----', '', $pemPkcs8);
$pemPkcs8 = str_replace('-----END PRIVATE KEY-----', '', $pemPkcs8);
$pemPkcs8 = trim($pemPkcs8);
$derPkcs8 = base64_decode($pemPkcs8);
$rawPrivate = substr($derPkcs8, -32);
$dt = sodium_crypto_box_seal_open($ct, $rawPrivate . $rawPublic);
print('decrypted:  ' .  $dt . PHP_EOL);
?>


If you need to use the old Ed25519 key pair: It is not possible to perform X25519 directly with an Ed25519 key pair. However, you can convert an Ed25519 key pair into an X25519 key pair due to the birational equivalence of curve25519 and edwards25519. PHP provides the functions sodium_crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519() and sodium_crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_curve25519() for this purpose.
Note that I could not test the above code on 7.4 because I do not have a test environment with this PHP version.
